# Symfony6 + php8 = composer ffmpeg installation dependency issue

Tags: php, ffmpeg, symfony6

I am trying to install `composer require php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg` but I get dependency error :

```
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg ^0.18.0 -> satisfiable by php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg[v0.18.0].
    - php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg v0.18.0 requires doctrine/cache ^1.0 -> found doctrine/cache[v1.0, ..., 1.12.1] but the package is fixed to 2.1.1 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
```

I don't understand how doctrine cache could be conflicting ?
I tried `-W` but I get even more errors ... ??

Could a composer guru help ?

my composer.json:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1.0",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-fileinfo": "*",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-imagick": "^3.6",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-openssl": "*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
        "doctrine/migrations": "^3.3",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.10",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "^4.0",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^5.8",
        "laminas/laminas-code": "4.5.x-dev as 4.5.0",
        "symfony/asset": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/cache": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/config": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/console": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/mime": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/validator": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "6.0.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.0.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.36",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "6.0.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.0.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error message seems quite clear. `php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg v0.18.0 requires doctrine/cache ^1.0 but the package is fixed to 2.1.1`. Looks like this ffmpeg package is pretty outdated.

Comment: @miken32 I have version 4.4.1_3 from homebrew

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone has opened a PR to fix this in the repo, but it hasn't been updated since March. In the meantime, there is [a workaround](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/pull/824#issuecomment-899341114), if you trust using a forked repo created by some random user:

```json
"require": {
  "php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg": "dev-psr"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/ekyna/PHP-FFMpeg.git"
    }
],
```

Comment: I would try but getting `GitHub API limit (0 calls/hr) is exhausted`

Comment: actually I got a token and tried but still exact same error; cannot install ffmpeg

Comment: you probably didn't clean things out first. `composer dump-autoload` , or just delete `vendor` directory and `composer.lock` file followed by `composer install`

Comment: same issue, deleted everything as suggested

Comment: It can’t possibly be the same issue. The composer.json on the forked repo does not require doctrine/cache.